# How do I insert variables in keys in Ansible/YAML?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, yaml

I have a variable declared, and I am trying to get its value to show up in the key, when attempting to use the ec2_instance_info ansible module. I want the value to show up under tags. Please view the dummy code below.

```
  vars:
    tag_key: Key
    tag_value: Value
  tasks:
   - name:
     ec2_instance_info:
     filters:
       "tag: {{ tag_key }}": "{{ tag_value }}"
```

I want the above to output as:

```
tag:Key:Value
```

But instead it comes out as:

```
tag:{{ tag_key }}:Value
```

As a result, when I run the commands, it doesn't call any instances, since they're searching for the wrong thing. The code works fine when I swap the variables out for regular strings. (I'm aware the syntax is probably wrong in the dummy code, I've tried a bunch of things now.)

I attempted the following: [Ansible variable in key/value key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47172551/ansible-variable-in-key-value-key) And while it works in displaying the variables, it now registers as a dict and I get the error:

> Invalid type for parameter Filters[0].Values, value: {'Key': 'Value'}, type: <type 'dict'>, valid types: <type 'list'>, <type 'tuple'>"

So I guess I'm looking for either a way to use variables in key names without it turning to a dict, and if that's not available, to transform that into a list. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filters` of `ec2_instance_info` module requires a "dict". So one way to supply that "dict" is to create one in `vars:`.

Something like:

```yml
  vars:
    ec2_filters:
      "tag:Name": "my-instance-1"

  tasks:
  - ec2_instance_info:
      filter: "{{ ec2_filters }}"
    register: ec2_out
  - debug:
      var: ec2_out
```

Or call the nested variables as a dict inside filters:

```yml
  vars:
    tag_key: Key
    tag_value: Value

  tasks:
  - ec2_instance_info:
      filter:
        '{ "tag:{{ tag_key }}": "{{ tag_value }}" }'
    register: ec2_out
```

Comment: Looks like this was exactly what I needed. Thank you.